# RTK-query hook tests using jest and Mock Service Worker cannot intercept data

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, vite, rtk-query, msw

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const { data: taxSystemData, isLoading } = useGetTaxSystemQuery();

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div data-testid="TaxationSystems">
      {taxSystemData?.length ? (
        <div>
          {taxSystemData?.map((item) => {
            return (
              <FormCheckbox
                data-testid={item.value}
                key={item.id}
                label={item.name}
                name={item.value}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      ) : (
        'Ошибка'
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

mockServer(dictionariesHandlers);

describe('TaxSystem', () => {
  it('should display taxation system', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, debug, queryByText } = renderTestApp(
      <TestComponent />
    );

    expect(queryByText(/loading.../i)).toBeInTheDocument();

    await waitFor(async () => {
      const taxationSystemsElement = getByTestId('TaxationSystems');
      const test1Checkbox = getByTestId('test1');

      expect(taxationSystemsElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(test1Checkbox).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    expect(queryByText(/loading.../i)).not.toBeInTheDocument();

    debug();
  });
});
```

ошибка:
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="test1"]

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style

```
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          data-testid="TaxationSystems"
        >
          Ошибка
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

dictionaries.mock.ts

```
import { ITaxSystem } from 'widgets/activate-cashier/api/dictionaries/dictionaries.model';

export const mockTaxSystem: ITaxSystem[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'test1',
    name: 'test1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'test2',
    name: 'test2',
  },
  
];
```

handlers.ts

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { ITaxSystem } from 'widgets/activate-cashier/api/dictionaries/dictionaries.model';
import { mockTaxSystem } from './dictionaries.mock';


export const dictionariesHandlers = [
  rest.get(`/dict/taxSystem`, (_, res, ctx) =>
    res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json<ITaxSystem[]>(mockTaxSystem))
  ),
];
```

mock-server.ts

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { DefaultBodyType, MockedRequest, RestHandler } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

global.fetch = fetch;

export const mockServer = (
  handlers: RestHandler<MockedRequest<DefaultBodyType>>[]
) => {
  const server = setupServer(...handlers);

  beforeAll(() => server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'warn' }));
  afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
  afterAll(() => server.close());

  return server;
};
```

fiscalizeDictionariesApi

```
import { api } from 'app/api';
import { ITaxSystem } from './dictionaries.model';
import { IFullResponse } from '../activate-cashier.model';

export const fiscalizeDictionariesApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getTaxSystem: build.query<ITaxSystem[], void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/dict/taxSystem',
      }),
      transformResponse: (response: IFullResponse<ITaxSystem[]>) => {
        return response.response;
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetTaxSystemQuery } = fiscalizeDictionariesApi;
```

in this block of code in response the data from the dictionaries.mock.ts file is correctly returned

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    server.listen();

    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/dict/taxSystem`);
    taxSystemData = await response.json();
    console.log('taxSystemData', taxSystemData);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    server.resetHandlers();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
  });
```

ошибка при запуске тестов:

```
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="test1"]

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          data-testid="TaxationSystems"
        >
          Ошибка
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with transformResponse which was returning reponse.response. If you return only response, then all tests pass and it works correctly.

```js
export const fiscalizeDictionariesApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getTaxSystem: build.query<ITaxSystem[], void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/dict/taxSystem',
      }),
      transformResponse: (response: IFullResponse<ITaxSystem[]>) => {
        return response;
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```